# Php worker Exception after idle time of 15 minutes

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I have written a php worker to fetch data from RabbitMQ queue.The php worker is running successfully as a background job on some server which connects RabbitMQ server for consuming data using AMQP php extension.After there is no data enqued in the queue for 15 minutes, php scripts throws AMQPException.
Exception is :

> AMQPException Object
>   (

```
[message:protected] => Library error: a socket error occurred
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 0
[file:protected] => /home/indiamart/public_html/dev-weberp-auto-dialer/merp/devworker.php
[line:protected] => 104
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/indiamart/public_html/dev-weberp-auto-dialer/merp/devworker.php
                [line] => 104
                [function] => consume
                [class] => AMQPQueue
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Closure Object
                            (
                                [parameter] => Array
                                    (
                                        [$message] => <required>
                                        [$q] => <required>
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[previous:Exception:private] =>
```

)

Below is my worker code:

```
  <?php
    $callback_func     = function(AMQPEnvelope $message, AMQPQueue $q){
    $data              = json_decode($message->getBody(), true);
    $getDeliveryTag    = $message->getDeliveryTag();
    $ack               = $q->ack($getDeliveryTag);//used $getDeliveryTag


    $to                = isset($data["to"])?$data["to"]:"";
    $subjectMail       = isset($data["subject"])?$data["subject"]:"";
    $mail_body_content = isset($data["body"])?"<pre>".$data["body"]."</pre>":"";
    $mailfrom          = isset($data["mailfrom"])?$data["mailfrom"]:"";
    $cc                = isset($data["cc"])?$data["cc"]:"";
    $mailfromname      = isset($data["mailfromname"])?$data["mailfromname"]:"";
    $uniqueid          = isset($data["unique_id"])?$data["unique_id"]:"";


    if(!$ack){//if ack not recieved
        $ack_msg = "Unique id: $uniqueid Subject : $subjectMail";
        @mail("abc@example.com","History Queue Not acknowledged!",$ack_msg);
    }
    if($message->isRedelivery()){
        $red_msg = "Unique id: $uniqueid Subject : $subjectMail";
        @mail("abc@example.com","History Queue Redilivery!",$red_msg);
    }



    $m_headers_trail =  "From:$mailfromname<$mailfrom> \n".
                        "Cc:$cc\n".
                        "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n".
                        "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";

    $flag = @mail($to,$subjectMail,$mail_body_content,$m_headers_trail);
    $flag_message = $flag ? "success unique id: $uniqueid Subject :$subjectMail" : "mail failed";

    @mail("abc@example.com","History Mailer Result",$flag_message);

 };


  $host     = "127.0.0.1";
  $vhost    = "/";
  $port     = 5672;
  $login    = "admin";
  $password = "admin"; 


  CHANNEL :
    try{
        @mail("abc@example.com","History Queue worker Start!","Worker 
        started!");
        $cnn = new AMQPConnection(array("host" => $host,"vhost" => $vhost,"port" 
        => $port,"login" => $login,"password" => $password));
        $cnn->connect();
        if(!$cnn){
            @mail("abc@example.com","History Queue Connection 
            Error!","Connection not established!");
        }
        $ch    = new AMQPChannel($cnn);
        $queue = new AMQPQueue($ch);

        $queue->setName('STS_UPDATE_MAIL');
        $queue->setFlags(AMQP_NOPARAM);

        $queue->consume($callback_func);


        $ch->close();
        $cnn->close();
    }catch(Exception $e){

        if ($ch->isConnected()) {
            $ch->close();
            @mail("abc@example.com","History Queue Closing 
            Connection!","Closed!"); 
        } 
        if ($cnn->isConnected()) {
            $cnn->close();
            @mail("abc@example.com","History Queue Closing 
            Connection!","Closed!"); 
        } 
        goto CHANNEL;
    }


?>
```

Comment: What is logged by RabbitMQ at the same time?

Comment: server is remote. I don't have access to log. Can you please point the direction what is causing the error?

Comment: Please carefully read [my response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/bdKIgUkfMc4/b5d6D8gaBAAJ), where I state this: "I recommend that you review the consumer example here because I don't believe you have written your consumer correctly: https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/blob/master/demo/amqp_consumer_exclusive.php". **Did you review your code like I asked?**

Comment: Yes Luke, Thank you for reaching and sharing the content but i am using amqp php extention,not this library.I m sharing the link for my used extention http://docs.php.net/manual/da/book.amqp.php

Comment: I see, that wasn't clear. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with that extension. If you can get the RabbitMQ log it will definitively show what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a library issue. I than shifted the worker in golang